# Get current window with shortcut initiated script

Tags: python, python-3.x, pywin32

I have a standard windows shortcut on my desktop that uses cmd to launch a python script. I have a key bound to launch said shortcut (lets say `SHIFT + F7`). I want my script to get the `HWND` (the id of the window in `win32gui`) of the current window when `SHIFT + F7` is pressed.

My issue is that when I press `SHIFT + F7`, the python script becomes the current window, and thus ***its*** `HWND` is found.

I thought that maybe using `pythonw.exe` instead of `python.exe` would do something, but the problem persists.

Here is the shortcut code:

```
C:\Windows\System32\cmd.exe /k "<path to pythonw.exe>" <path to script>
```

And here's the script itself:

```
from win32 import win32gui

cur_hwnd = win32gui.GetForegroundWindow()
text = win32gui.GetWindowText(cur_hwnd)

with open(r"<path to output file>", "w") as fp:
    fp.write(text)
```

What should I do differently to get the window id? It would technically work to have a long running python script in the background that waits for `SHIFT + F7` and then records the current id, but I would rather not do that.

---

EDIT 1:

When `<path to pythonw.exe> <path to script>` is used in the schortcut instead, the process found by `win32gui.GetForegroundWindow()` is an unknown one with an empty window text (there are many such programs running and I’m not sure what they are).

Also, to clarify, the `SHIFT + F7` combo is set in the shortcut’s preferences window.

Comment: Try making the shortcut simply  `"<path to pythonw.exe>" "<path to script>"`

Comment: @martineau That has rather strange results... When I use `SHIFT + F7`, the output file is emptied, and when I double-click the shortcut, the file says "Program Manager". EDIT: To clarify, when using `SHIFT + F7`, I do have a window focussed.

Comment: I meant create a shortcut as I described on your desktop and then make `SHIFT + F7` execute _the shortcut_.

Comment: @martineau I think that that is what I’ve been doing. I have updated the question. Thank you for your continued help.

Comment: Perhaps it's because your app doesn't have a window to get (and therefore there's no window text to get either). What would you expect to get if the `GetForegroundWindow()` worked?

Comment: @martineau I’m doing the tests with my web browser window, so the title text should say chrome or something. The `HWND` that `GetForegroundWindow()` returns is the same regardless of the actual window focussed :/